# DXGI text output trail

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, gdi

I'm trying to move text by TextOut

here is code

```
IDXGISurface1* g_pSurface1 = NULL;
HRESULT hr = pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(IDXGISurface1), (void**)&g_pSurface1);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = g_pSurface1->GetDC(FALSE, &hdc);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {


        TextOut(hdc, pos.x, pos.y, L"DXGI's GDI text output works", strlen("DXGI's GDI text output works") + 1);

        g_pSurface1->ReleaseDC(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
    }
    g_pSurface1->Release();
}
else
{
    MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
}
pDevContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pRenderTarget, pDepth);
```

where

```
 pos.x and pos.y are mouse coordinates
```

and when I'm moving text or child window [GDI and DirectX rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501491/gdi-and-directx-rendering)

I have this[image]

Comment: Why are you using GDI rather than DirectWrite?

Comment: Because I can't use DirectWrite

Comment: Why not? It's not clear from your question as to why you are using the older GDI interop?

Comment: generally I want to use Qt , so DirectWrite is not cross platform.

Comment: Ok, but GDI isn't cross platform either.

Comment: Yes I know but if I can do it in GDI then I can modify Qt's GUI kernel for it.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` is for ANSI, it cannot be mixed with Unicode. Instead use "wide-c-string" functions **wcs**xxx. For example `wcslen`:

```
const wchar_t* text = L"DXGI's GDI text output works";
TextOut(hdc, pos.x, pos.y, text, wcslen(text));
```

To get rid of the trail, you have to erase the background manually. For example:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

    //erase background:
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(128, 128, 255));
    FillRect(hdc, &rc, brush);
    DeleteObject(brush);

    //draw text:
    const wchar_t *text = L"DXGI's GDI text output works";
    SetBkMode(hdc, OPAQUE);
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,255,255));
    TextOut(hdc, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), text, wcslen(text));
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    break;
}
```

Edit, mixing this with Direct3D

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    //call directx rendering to reset the background:
    Render(); 

    //draw text:
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    const wchar_t *text = L"DXGI's GDI text output works";
    SetBkMode(hdc, OPAQUE);
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,255,255));
    TextOut(hdc, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), text, wcslen(text));
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    break;
}
```

Comment: is here any other way to clear background without color filling ?

Comment: because I also have realtime DirectX rendering on same window where I'm rendering text by GDI

Comment: That would be relatively easy if background is solid color. But in your case you have to save the background as bitmap. Use `DrawText` instead of `TextOut`, restore the old text rectangles. It would be easier to paint the entire background. You can use DirectX to paint to a buffer to speed up repainting. In your case you may want to focus on previous question where you use a child window instead.

Comment: Note, if you are rendering direct3d in a loop, it is painting at 30 frames per seconds (or whatever frame rate you have). So that's not a solid background, but it is animation which looks static. What happens here is that the rendering in the main loop stops while you are holding down the mouse button, so you just have to call `Render()` function yourself. You could do all of the drawing in DirectX, you don't really need GDI. See edit.